# Combining Numpy Arrays Feature Matrices In Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the data with `38910 rows and 2 columns`. As its a string data, so I used two feature creation methods A and B.

Method A gives me data of numpy arrays of the shape as:

```
a.shape = (38910, 17, 21)
```

Method B gives me data of numpy arrays of the shape as:

```
b.shape = (38910, 16, 441)
```

Now, for applying Convolution Neural Network and other methods, I need to combine both the features to make a numpy array of the `shape = (38910, 17, 21, 16, 441)`. What is the best way I can do that such that I don't face memory issues.

Comment: Could you say more about why you need to fit the entire dataset into memory at once? Is it possible for you to assemble the rows in batches and save them to disk, then load them in batches as you are training?

Comment: Not any specific reason for that, but it seems a easy job as I am beginner in this field. So, I don't have any knowledge to assemble rows in batches, save them to disk and then load. If you can answer my question including the assembling, saving and loading rows, I will be highly thankful @MatthewCox

Comment: **it seems a easy job**: You are asking to put a huge data into the memory without *facing memory issues*. I don't think it's that easy. You don't need to assemble the batches, save to disk and load. But rather think about batches as `(a_part, b_part)` where each component is a small part of the bigger counter-part, say of length `100`. In doing so, you effectively replacing `38910` with `100`, which makes your problem a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

One one to avoid memory issues is to process the rows in batches. Assuming that you have a function `combine_features(a, b)` that combines the outputs of method A and method B, here's a rough outline of a solution:

```
a_batches = np.array_split(a, 500)
b_batches = np.array_split(b, 500)
for i, batch in enumerate(zip(a_batches, b_batches)):
  a_batch, b_batch = batch
  output = combine_features(a_batch, b_batch)
  np.save(f"{destination_folder}/data-{i}.npy", output)
```

Then as you are training, you can iterate through the saved files and load one at a time.